# (simple) Expectation of random variable as a multipart function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let the random variable $Y \in [0, \infty)$, a real number $\theta >0$, and the random variable $X$ such that $X = \theta - \min(\theta,Y)$, thus, $X \in [0, \theta]$. That is, $X = 0$ if $Y > \theta$ and $X = \theta-Y$ if $Y \leq \theta$. I would like to know if the expectation of $X$, $E[X] = E[\theta-Y|Y \leq \theta] P(Y \leq \theta) = (\theta-E[Y|Y\leq \theta])P(Y \leq \theta)=\theta P(Y \leq \theta)-\int_{0}^{\theta}y f_{Y}(y)dy$ is valid.
If so, since $E[X] >0$, then, $\theta P(Y \leq \theta) > \int_{0}^{\theta}y f_{Y}(y)dy$ (?) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are valid. The inequality at the end is direct since
$$
\theta P[Y\leqslant\theta]=\int_0^\theta \theta f_Y(y)\mathrm dy\geqslant\int_0^\theta y f_Y(y)\mathrm dy=E[Y;Y\leqslant\theta].
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct.  It's the same idea as [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_inequality).